# limit pitch of camera between two values

Tags: c#, xna, camera, pitch

I'm having trouble trying to pitch my camera within a specified range. Currently, my camera can pitch around the model without any constraints. I've tried to limit the Y-Axis between a range of 6 and 36, but if I keep pitching, the Z-Axis will continue moving the camera forward.

I'm using a controller thumbstick to control the movement. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is: "If the camera's angle to the target(model) is more than the angle of my limit, keep the camera at the limit regardless of if more pitch (person continuously holding the thumbstick up or down) is applied."

**NOTE: This is a 3rd-Person Camera**

```
    public void cameraPitch(float pitch)
    {  
        cameraDirection = ModelLoad.CameraPos - ModelLoad.camTarget;
        axisPitch = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Up, cameraDirection);

        // pitch constrained to model's orientation
        axisPitch.Normalize();

        ModelLoad.CameraPos = Vector3.Transform(cameraDirection,
            Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(axisPitch, pitch)) + ModelLoad.camTarget;

        if (ModelLoad.camPos.Y > 36.0f)
        {
            ModelLoad.camPos.Y = 36.0f;
        }

        if (ModelLoad.camPos.Y < 6.0f)
        {
            ModelLoad.camPos.Y = 6.0f;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with the camera's X or Y position in space whatsoever. To solve this issue you will need to store the total amount of the camera's pitch within this `ModelLoad` object of yours, or anywhere else where it can persist really. Then just check this value before applying the matrix transformation to the camera's position vector, acually, check it before doing any of that stuff... yeah, so if the current amount of pitch is equal to 36 just exit the method without doing anything, if it's not, rotate the camera and don't forget to add this new amount to the total.

And I don't quite remember but I think the angle you pass to the `Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle` has to be in radians, right? So don't check for 36, check for 36 converted to radians. (Pretend you didn't know that haha)